# Is region-specific blocking built-in to MacOS more extensive than a few emoji?

Tags: macos, mac

[This answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/328519/143729) to the question

> Can't see this emoji  on macOS

provides some insight into two ways that seeing a particular emoji will be blocked by macOS in some cases:

> - The device (Mac or iOS device) is bought from mainland China, determined by hardware serial number
> - The "Region" setting is set to China

Is it known if this kind of region-specific blocking is limited to a few emoji, or is it more extensive in some cases?

I'm looking ideally for an answer that's backed up with an authoritative source of some kind. Not anecdotal experiences or guesses.

Comment: I've made some adjustments to the question. Helpful comments welcome.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Have you looked over https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask - this still seems quite hypothetical “what if Apple is blocking more” and reads more like a wiki list or article on what Apple decided to do in one region. Is there a specific practical thing you’re trying to do or just open discussion on the general topic of Chinese modifications so multiple shipping operating systems?