# My emoji in Google Hangouts flip-flops on my MacBook, why?

Tags: emoji

A few days after I asked my (now closed) question [Is region-specific blocking built-in to MacOS more extensive than a few emoji?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/328950/143729) the emoji shown in Google Hangouts in the Chrome browser on my MacBook Air flipped from "my original emoji" to "my new emoji".

Then a few days ago, it flipped back to original in Hangous, for a few minutes, then flipped back again to "my new emoji".

I don't really know where emoji "live" or how they get into Hangouts, but I especially don't understand how it could flip-fpop back and forth like this.

Is there a way I can stabilize this on my computer? Is this a decision made in my OS or in Chrome? Can I somehow set Hangouts it to "my old emoji" permanently?

Here is one example of the two emoji sets:

"my old emoji" [image: "my old emoji"] (Google?)

"my new emoji" [image: "my new emoji"] (Apple?)

Comment: Both emojis are Google's. Google just updated the look of the emoji because people didn't like the "blob" emoji

Comment: Computers do not see Emoji, they see the code for it (
Unicode: U+1F601, UTF-8: F0 9F 98 81), what the code displays depends on what Emoji graphics is used to display it by the application it self or OS X

Comment: @Buscar웃 got it! My question includes exactly that: "...is it the application itself, or OS X" in the case of Hangouts in Chrome on MacOS.

Comment: Correct, the computers send each other the Unicode (the universal character code) what they make out of it it depends, like emoji will look different on different devices (operating systems). Try hangouts on your phone and see. Look in your Emoji list on your mac and see the choices. Emoji are just characters.

Comment: @Buscar웃 in this case, I am asking if it is the application or the system. Do you know?

Comment: see also this answer https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/214659/46541

Comment: @Buscar웃 that answer mentions `/System/Library/Fonts/Apple Color Emoji.ttf` which is a strange place for *[Google to store Google fonts](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/339487/my-emoji-in-google-hangouts-flip-flops-on-my-macbook-why?noredirect=1#comment440094_339487)*, wouldn't you say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both emojis are Google's, they have nothing to do with Apple's emojis.

Many people didn't like Google's "blob" emojis, so Google changed it to this new one.