# Is there any difference between Macs sold in China and US except the Taiwan flag?

Tags: mac

I wonder if there is any more difference between the Macs sold in China and USA, except that Chinese models don't show the Taiwan flag (), as explained [in this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/328474/cant-see-this-emoji-on-macos).

I'm in China and am considering buying it, but wonder if it is fine to buy it here or move to another country (not necessarily USA; countries not having such restrictions such as Japan are fine) to buy it. I would not like to find any regional restrictions only after I purchased it.

Comment: Yeah, probably no news app in Mojave. Or if it's there, it will be significantly bad. (Due to Chinese regulations; god forbid a citizen sees something bad about China in the news‍♂️)

Comment: Keyboard maybe different

Comment: @JBis Actually, the news app is not available in China, even on Macs purchased outside of China. (I’m in China and run Mojave Beta). As to the keyboard, you can choose whatever you want if you buy it in Apple Store Online, though the options available depend on each country.

Comment: Yeah didn't think it was. Wonder what would happen if I gave you the news app....(I'd give it if you want. If so @JBis me in chat). Yes, keyboard can be chosen but it will most likely default to Chinese keyboard.

Comment: Chinese iOS devices allow you to restrict per-app network access: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/312430/19829